# Rendering tiles Java Libgdx

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, tiles

I am trying to render a tiled map that generate random tiles each time the game is run.

I have an array that is supposed to hold all of the values for the tiles, that are then changed at random:

```
int[][] map = {
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
            };
         for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
                if(map[x][y] == 0){
                    switch(MathUtils.random(2)){                    
                    case 0:
                        map[x][y] = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        map[x][y] = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        map[x][y] = 2;
                        break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

I then render them according to what the tiles are:

```
public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        game.batch.begin();
         for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[y].length; y++) {
                if(map[x][y] == 1){
                    game.batch.draw(stone, x*120, y*120);
                }
                if(map[x][y] == 2){
                    game.batch.draw(grass, x*120, y*120);
                }
                if(map[x][y] == 0){
                    game.batch.draw(dirt, x*120, y*120);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Problem:**

1. All of the rendered tiles are dirt.
2. It really slows everything down.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `map[x].length;` in `for (int y = 0; y < map[y].length; y++)` in `render` method?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR Yes that would make sense but i just changed it and it rased the error: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9

Comment: Put some `1`s and `2`s in your initial `map`. That will determine if there is an error in your random placement or in your drawing code. (At a glance, it *should* have worked. Also check your image loading code. Maybe you are not loading the correct images.)

Comment: @Jongware adding 1s and 2s does not change the map, the image loading code is correct, and unless i put x here when it should be y :map[x].length;       i get an error

Comment: Ah wait. Since you posted only snippets, I might be wrong, but: where is `int[][] map` declared?

Comment: @Jongware It was  int[][] map = new int[1920][1080];,     But i just changed it to:       int[][] map = new int[16][9];
    Hense solving the slowing problem

Comment: @Jongware but it still only renders 'dirt'

Comment: I mean, is your `map` a global variable? It looks like your drawing code works (after all, you get to see *something*), but your random placement function does *not* -- even if you hardcode other values. (As for the slowness, you probably should render only the visible part, not the entire map. That's another discussion, less important at the moment.)

Comment: @Jongware sorry but i just solved the porblem it seems that i already had another 'map' variable and it was reading the values from that, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. It really slows everything down

This is caused by the large size of your map: 1920 x 1080 blocks. With each of your tiles at 120 x 120 pixels, this is as much as 230,400 x 129,600 pixels. Rendering all of them is not a problem for OpenGL, since it will automatically clip everything not visible, and OpenGL is efficient in determining visibility. But *before* you send it off to the batch renderer, you are already doing a whole lot of work that can easily be avoided.

(The following code snippets may not be proper Java.)

1. Do not use `if` -- or even the better `switch` -- inside the inner drawing loop. Create an indexed lookup array:

   ```
   Texture textures[] = { dirt, stone, grass };
   ```

   and then inside the loops use:

   ```
   game.batch.draw(textures[map[x][y]], x*120, y*120);
   ```
2. Do not draw the entire map. Calculate the current viewport (the part of the map that shows up on your screen) and only draw that.
   Maintain a coordinate pair `mapx`,`mapy` that holds the top left coordinates of your map on screen. Moving this coordinate pair will make the map move around on your screen. If you want your "player" to always stay in the exact center of the screen, it can be as simple as `mapx = (player_x - screen_width/2)`. Take care to check for out-of-range values.

   The part of the map that will be visible starts at

   ```
   int tile_xoffset = floor (mapx/120);
   int tile_yoffset = floor (mapy/120);
   ```

   rounding down, because if `mapx` is `119` you will still see a one-pixel strip of `map[0][y]`. (Minor note: `floor` is actually unnecessary. Java automatically rounds down when converting a float to integer.)

   The width (and similar, the height) of the visible part in 120x120 map blocks can be calculated as

   ```
   screen_width/120
   ```

   but that is only the number of *whole* map blocks that is visible. You need to draw a 'border' as well, of blocks that are only partially visible.

   A more accurate calculation should be this (warning: untested!):

   ```
   int vis_width = (screen_width + (mapx % 120) + (120-(screen_width % 120)))/120;
   ```
3. A good general principle is to do as little calculation as possible in inner loops. The multiplication by `120` for each tile can easily be replaced with an addition. It's also not necessary to do this for *both* `x` and `y` inside the innermost loop.
4. After doing all of the above calculations, check if `tile_xoffset` is not less than 0, and `tile_xoffset + visible_width` is less than the width of your tile map; and, of course, the same for the y part.

---

Putting all of this together, your map drawing code should look something like this:

```
xp = (tile_xoffset*120) - mapx;
for (int x = 0; x < visible_width; x++)
{
    yp = (tile_yoffset*120) - mapy;
    for (int y = 0; y < visible_height; y++)
    {
        game.batch.draw(textures[map[x][y]], xp, yp);
        yp += 120;
    }
    xp += 120;
}
```

---

To draw characters on top of this map, you can offset their coordinates by `-mapx,-mapy`. If you have lots of additional characters, another speed-up can be gained by first testing if they are inside the visible boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

The 'map' array, was not actually the array that the data was being rendered from there was a previous array which corrupted and led to duplication of data.